# setNamedRange won't take a string variable as the "name"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am attempting a simple bit of code that creates a new sheet in a spreadsheet, then creates a few named ranges from that sheet. I get the error "the name given to this range is invalid" when attempting to use a variable of type String as the "name" in ss.setNamedRange(name, range) as follows:

```
function addNewInventoryItem() {

var itemName = "new item";
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName("New Inventory Item Template");

// duplicate the template sheet, then set the new name of the sheet and the first cell of the sheet to be the itemName
var itemSheet = templateSheet.copyTo(ss);
    itemSheet.showSheet();  // unhide the new sheet
    itemSheet.setName(itemName);  // set the sheet name
    itemSheet.getRange(1,1).setValue(itemName);  // set the item name as sheet header (cell 1,1)

// create named ranges for qty column and unit cost column
var qtyRangeName = itemName;
var ucRangeName = itemName + "UC";

    ss.setNamedRange(qtyRangeName, itemSheet.getRange(6,3,10,1));
    ss.setNamedRange(ucRangeName, itemSheet.getRange(6,5,10,1));
}
```

I've tried getting rid of the variables and typing in strings manually into the setNamedRange formula and it works. I've also confirmed that my variables are strings, and even tried forcing them to strings before sending them to setNamedRange just for the hell of it, and it still didn't work.

Anybody have any ideas? Having to type in the string manually defeats the entire purpose of using apps script for this as far as i can tell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is that the name of the named range includes the space like `new item`. So for example, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
var qtyRangeName = itemName;
var ucRangeName = itemName + "UC";
```

#### To:

```
var qtyRangeName = itemName.replace(/ /g, "_");
var ucRangeName = itemName.replace(/ /g, "_") + "UC";
```

- In this modification,   is replaced with `_`.

#### Note:

- In this case, when the named range is manually created with the name including the space, an error occurs. From this situation, I proposed above modification.
- This is a sample modification. So please modify above for your actual situation.

#### References:

- [setNamedRange(name, range)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#setnamedrangename,-range)
- [Name a range of cells](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/63175?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)

Comment: perfect!! thank you! does your modified code there replace all spaces in itemName with "_" or just the first space?

Comment: @theunspeakablethings Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. In this modification, all spaces in `itemName` are replaced with `_` like from `aa bb cc` to `aa_bb_cc`.